Can I use IIS server rewrite or DNS to override links that use shortname URL instead of FQDN?
I have a project I've been working on where my servers are Windows and use IIS. I have pages and pages of documentation, forms, and so on where the URLs to the server are all shortname style. Ex. https://contoso/restofstuff instead of the proper https://testserver.contoso.com/restofstuff.
I know it's slacker to use shortnames and is a security problem so I'm trying to do this properly, but is there a lazy way out that doesn't involve updating hundreds of links manually? Destination is a test SharePoint server I'm toying with.
Can I use DNS rules or IIS rewrite/redirect to alter the URL manually? Specifically, if the cert (which I used to have shortnames explicitly allowed) is changed to only allow FQDN, can I click a shortname link, have it translated to FQDN automatically, and the server be cool with it from a certificate standpoint?
